# Adding files to a nested zip python

Tags: python, nested, zip

I have a `child.zip` inside another zip `master.zip`
I want to add a file `str.txt`  to the child.zip

The structure is something like this:

> - master.zip
>
>   - child.zip
>
>     - str.txt

Here is my attempts:

```
def writeadapt():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('master.zip','a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zfile:
        for name in zfile.namelist():
            if re.search(r'\.zip$', name ) != None:
                zfiledata = io.BytesIO(zfile.read(name))
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata , 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zfile2:
                    zfile2.writestr('str.txt',"hello")
                    zfile2.close()
```

The code does not add the file str.txt to child.zip.

What is the best way to add a file to a nested zip ?

Comment: Re: "does not seem to work". Please explain what exactly that means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a child.zip inside another zip master.zip I want to add a file str.txt to the child.zip

If at all possible, you need to rethink this design altogether.

Adding a file to a ZIP archive requires the archive to be written to. However, files stored within ZIP archives are not writable -- they can be replaced with new files, but not updated in place -- so it is not possible to directly write a file to a nested ZIP archive.

Your code is not working as expected because updating the ZIP archive in `zfiledata` does not update the corresponding data in the parent archive. (It is, after all, just a `BytesIO` object.) You would need to write that data back to the parent archive to persist your changes. However, as I noted previously, this will be a slow and expensive operation -- particularly if the archive is large -- so it should be avoided.